# Server tries to re transmit packets even after receiving RST from the client

Tags: java, networking, tcp

We have a server running Jboss on port 443 and a client which communicates with it. The client hits a https servlet.

In the wireshark traces I see that once the application level communication is done. The client sends it FIN and also sends a RST, but the server still retires sending its packet(closing the TLS connection from its end) even after receiving a RST and the client again sends a RST(which I guess is expected). This re-transmission continues.

Any thoughts on what could go wrong causing this?

I can share the network traces. At the moment it is not allowing me to attach images.

Comment: Packet capture is done before packet processing, so the server probably did not process the RST yet.

Comment: That should not be the case I was capturing the packets on the server side itself also the re-transmissions continue for a few seconds.

Comment: I think you should add packet captures. Best not as a picture but using cloudshark.org.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share a location where I can put it? cloudshark is not allowed to be accessed from my organization.